# What to use for graphql with nodejs

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql, prisma-graphql

I started looking into graphql to use it as a server in the next project instead of REST.
As I started I was bombarded with lots of options.
**graphql-yoga**, **express-graphql**, **apollo** and so on

I want to know which one is the most widely used option and has a comparatively large community.

Comment: Pick whatever you prefer and think is the right solution. If you're looking for "the most widely used option" then I guess you could check the download stats on `npmjs.com`  for each of them. `apollo-server-express` has about 908k weekly downloads, which is the most out of the 3, but I'd suggest to figure out the pros and cons for all of them and make your decision based on that.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.npmjs.com/

- **apollo-server-express** - 997,081 downloads/week
- **express-graphql** - 375,403 downloads/week
- **graphql-yoga** - 24,100 downloads/week

As per ease of use,

I think it is better start & learn with **express-graphql** as it is easier. After understanding graphql you can then start learing & using **apollo-server-express** and use it for any further purposes.